# pip3 install doesn't install anything in my docker image

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pip, jupyter-notebook

So, here's the problem:

I am trying to build and run a jupyter notebook inside the docker container. At some point I need to install a few python packages with pip3 install. The build looks fine, all the modules are being installed, but when I import any of those modules inside the jupyter notebook, it says `"No module named <module_name>"`, as if it wasn't installed.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook

LABEL maintainer="Jupyter Project <jupyter@googlegroups.com>"

USER root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    python3-pip

RUN sudo -H pip3 install matplotlib \
    pillow \
    numpy

USER $NB_UID
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: Your Dockerfile is missing the `COPY` step to bring your application in, and the `CMD` to run it.  You also don’t need `sudo` at all (especially since you’re explicitly running as `USER root`).

Comment: @DavidMaze I omitted the `ADD` steps from that listing, I properly copy all the data I need into the image. And the CMD command is run from the base image I believe, since the notebook is being started without any CMD commands in my Dockerfile explicitly.

Comment: if you can share log of your build it will helps us to find solution.
Try replace python3-pip with python-pip

Comment: @DavidMaze if I don't use sudo, I get a warning `The directory '/home/jovyan/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.`